# Docker Python ImportError when started inline with container

Tags: python, docker

I am having an odd problem when running a python script in a docker container.
When I start the script in the same line as I am starting the docker containter e.g.

```
docker run -it --rm <containter>:<version> /bin/bash --login -c "python /opt/project/main.py"
```

It raises an `ImportError` for a module.
However when I first start the docker conainer and **afterwards** start the script afterwards

```
docker run -it --rm <containter>:<version> /bin/bash 
python /opt/project/main.py
```

everything behaves as it should. So only when i start the script in the same line, the issue occurs.

Hope you can give me a heads-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution which I am happy to share with a random googlers:

The issue I had was that the python dependencies I used were source build catkin dependencies. Thus the `setup.bash` file from the catkin workspace needed to be sourced in order for the libraries to be found. Since the `.bashrc` is not sourced when starting the docker like I mentioned, it as to be done manually:

```
docker run -it --rm <containter>:<version> /bin/bash --login -c "source /path/to/setup.bash  && python /opt/project/main.py"
```